# java move image with mouse

Tags: java, image, mouse, move

i want to put this image on a map, so i want:
- click a button and make a new image
- move the image with the mouse and when click the image must be on the jpanel and not move anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[Use the jpanel as a canvas](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingJPanelasacanvas.htm) to draw the map and the image at a certain position.

Listen to the [mouse move events](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/MouseMotionEventmousemoveanddrag.htm), change the position of the image to the current position of the mouse. Redraw the canvas.

Add a [mouse click listener](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/Handlemousebuttonclickevent.htm) and when you get a click, disable the mouse move listener.